# How to make a URL desktop shortcut have the page's favicon?

Tags: browser, home-screen-shortcuts

Theoretically, it should do this automatically. In practice, sometimes it works, sometimes not. All the pages below have proper favicons, but only the O Globo and Amazon favicons made it to the desktop icon. (The former in a better way, as you can see.) I added them the usual way, with Menu -> Add -> Shortcut -> Bookmark.

This is a (rooted) Milestone running Motorola's official 2.2.1 update. These are the pages involved:

- http://moglobo.globo.com
- http://cracked.com
- http://mobile.formula1.com
- https://mobile.twitter.com
- http://www.amazon.com
- http://www.supervia.com.br

Any reason for that erratic behavior?

[image: home screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with the site having an icon for "apple-touch" defined in the page. for example O Globe has the following:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon.png" />
```

And it works. There are differences in how other versions of android handle this. [Here is an article](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/android-apple-touch-icon/) explaining some how this works a bit. There could also be a "catch 22" to this though, as I see that the mobile Twitter site does have the `apple-touch-icon-precomposed` but doesn't seem to show the icon. This could be because of something Motorola did differently in their modified version of Android, or it could just be a bug.

If the site does not define the icon, then you can use a tool like [Any Cut](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appdroid.anycut&feature=search_result) to change the icon.

Comment: It seems "Any Cut" app is removed from Play Store.